# how to set a default picture in an imageview in a list in android?

Tags: android, listview, bitmap, imageview, drawable

I want to show a default picture when the result is null and here is my try:

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(src);
                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    connection.setDoInput(true);
                    connection.connect();
                    InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                    connection.disconnect();
                    return myBitmap;
                } catch (IOException e) {
        //          tasvirdimg.setImageResource(R.drawable.p3_books);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
```

a class to use `getBitmapFromURL`:

```
class RetrievePic extends AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap>{

                    @Override
                    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
                        String url = urls[0];
                        return JSONCommands.getBitmapFromURL(url);
                    }   
    }
```

execute `RetrievePic` class in `ListAdapter`:

```
RetrievePic retPic = new RetrievePic();
retPic.execute(JSONCommands.firstURL + MainActivity.books_array.get(position).tasvir);
Bitmap img = null;
try {
    img = retPic.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    tasvirlimg.setImageResource(R.drawable.p3_books);
            e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    tasvirlimg.setImageResource(R.drawable.p3_books);
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    tasvirlimg.setImageBitmap(img);
```

when the picture is null it doesn't show any thing but it should show the default picture which is `R.drawable.p3_books`. thanks to your helps.

Comment: you can use [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) or [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) for downloading your images and also set a default image to your place holders.

Comment: I'm wondering people come here and edit questions and etc to get stars!!!! pleas just help me with my prob!

Comment: @MohammadRahchamani tank you but can you help me with my own code?!!

Comment: I think you should set default picture in if/else statement instead of catch block.

Comment: @MohammadRahchamani Yes . I did that but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
if(img == null) 
{ 
     tasvirlimg.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.p3_books); 
}
else
{ 
     tasvirlimg.setImageBitmap(img);
}
```

Comment: it has errors honey! tasvirlimg is an ImageView and doesn't have setImageBitmap class.

Comment: Try tasvirling.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.p3_books); instead of setImageBitmap(..). If this shouldnt work for you. You can try the example Jeffrey Blattman posted, this should work too.

Comment: did you see my code dear? as R.drawable.p3_books is a Resource I'v tried tasvirdimg.setImageResource(R.drawable.p3_books); thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why not set the default pic of item in xml and then the default pic would be replaced when result is not null

```
  <ImageView 
     ...
         android:src="@drawable/p3_books"
        />
```

EDIT:

```
        class RetrievePic extends AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap>{

     final image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.limg_tasvir);

            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
                String url = urls[0];
                return JSONCommands.getBitmapFromURL(url);
            }

            @Override
                    protected void onPreExecute() {
                         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                        image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.p3_books);
                                }
                            });

        }
}
```

Comment: this is my ImageView:
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/limg_tasvir"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/p3_books"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left" />
as you can see I set this option but It doesn't work!

Comment: runOnUiThread and tasvirdimg is 2 errors. I have  tasvirdimg in another class and I don't know about runOnUiThread .

Comment: @NiloofarHakkaki - I just noticed and changed it to tasvirlimg - if runonuithread giving errors, take it out -  protected void onPreExecute() {  tasvirlimg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.p3_books);    }

Comment: tasvirlimg  and tasvirdimg both are in other classes:) the class of bitmap is exclusive .

Comment: @NiloofarHakkaki - have you tried making them static to be able to access them - I need to see more code or error logcat - you should be setting the default pic to whichever you findViewById limg_tasvir

Answer (score 0):

what you want to do is in your implementation of your adapter's `getView()` method, something like this,

```
...
final imageView = ...;
imageView.setImageBitmap(defaultBitmap);
new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Bitmap>() {
  public Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // get bitmap from `net, or return null if failure
  }

  public void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    if (result != null) {
      imageView.setBitmap(result);
    }
  }
}.execute();
```

this way, the default is set. if you happen to get the network result, change the default.

Comment: I can't understand really:))) please explain it with example for a 15 reputation to understand!!! thank you